# Replacing Value with String from Lookup Table

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute code like this:

```
value = value.replace(/{{(.*)}}/g, this.dataService.relationTable["\"$1\""]);
```

I'd like to capture the variable inside of a string that has {{ and }} around it. Then I'd like to use that value to search through an object called this.dataService.relationTable and find the key string that is equal to the regex captured value.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Sample relationTable:

```
{C5: 200000, C7: 0, C6: 0, C8: "Site-Built", C26: 25, …}
C5
:
200000
C6
:
0
C7
:
0
C8
:
"Site-Built"
C11
:
4.25
C12
:
360
C13
:
3
C14
:
1000
C15
:
0
C16
:
0
C17
:
5000
C20
:
80
C21
:
8
C22
:
1000
C23
:
8
C24
:
0
C25
:
0
C26
:
25
C29
:
2000
C30
:
275
C31
:
250
C32
:
875
F4
:
"{{C5}}"
F5
:
"{{C7}}"
F6
:
"{{I21}}"
F7
:
"{{F24}}"
F8
:
"{{C29}}"
F9
:
"{{F4}} + {{F5}} + {{F6}} + {{F7}} + {{F8}}"
F11
:
"{{F9}}"
F12
:
"{{C6}}"
F13
:
"{{F11}} + {{F12}}"
F15
:
"{{C5}}"
F16
:
"{{C7}}"
F17
:
"{{C6}}"
F18
:
"{{F15}} + {{F16}} + {{F17}}"
F20
:
"{{F27}}"
F21
:
"{{C30}}"
F22
:
"{{C31}}"
F23
:
"{{C32}}"
F24
:
"{{F20}} + {{F21}} + {{F22}} + {{F23}}"
F26
:
"{{I11}}"
F27
:
"{{F26}} * 9 / 400"
I4
:
"{{F18}}"
I5
:
"{{F24}}"
I6
:
"{{C29}}"
I7
:
"{{C17}}"
I8
:
"{{I35}}"
I9
:
"{{I26}}"
I10
:
"{{C14}} * -1"
I11
:
"{{I4}} + {{I5}} + {{I6}} + {{I7}} + {{I8}} + {{I9}} - {{I10}}"
I13
:
"{{I11}}"
I14
:
"{{C11}}"
I15
:
"{{C12}}"
I16
:
undefined
I18
:
"{{I35}}"
I19
:
"{{C15}}"
I20
:
"{{C17}}"
I21
:
"{{I18}} + {{I19}} + {{I20}}"
I23
:
"{{F13}}"
I24
:
"{{C14}} * -1"
I25
:
"{{C13}}"
I26
:
"({{I23}} + {{I24}}) * {{I25}}"
I28
:
"{{C20}} * {{C21}}"
I29
:
"{{C22}} * {{C23}}"
I30
:
"{{C24}} * {{C25}}"
I31
:
"{{C16}} * -1"
I32
:
"{{C11}} * {{C26}} / 365"
I33
:
"{{C20}} * 12"
I34
:
"{{C24}} * 12"
I35
:
"{{I28}} + {{I29}} + {{I30}} + {{I31}} + {{I32}} + {{I33}} + {{I34}}"
```

Sample value:

```
{{I35}}
```

In this case, the result should be {{I28}} + {{I29}} + {{I30}} + {{I31}} + {{I32}} + {{I33}} + {{I34}}

Comment: says $1 is not defined

Comment: value could be any string

Comment: Just added examples of both

Comment: Is that table supposed to be JSON? A String?

Comment: It's copied from Google chrome console... it's a JS Object

Comment: @user2476265 - right click the object in the chrome console, choose "store as global variable" - it will show something like `temp1`. In the console write copy(temp1), and paste the text whenever you want.

Comment: I believe this is an X/Y problem. You likely just want: `var key=“I35”, value=relationTable[key]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function as the replacement:

```
value = value.replace(/{{(.*)}}/g, (match, p1) => this.dataService.relationTable[p1]);
```

Here, the value `p1` will take on the value matched within the first capturing group `(...)` in the regular expression.

Comment: And you have to take the 2nd param (the 1st capture group), and not the match itself.

Comment: You are answering an X/Y problem. He needs to search an object for a value or set of values

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an X/Y problem. You likely just want: var key=“I35”, value=relationTable[key]

```js
var relationTable = {  C5: 200000,  C6: 0,  C7: 0,  C8: "Site-Built",  C11: 4.25,  C12: 360,  C13: 3,  C14: 1000,  C15: 0,  C16: 0,  C17: 5000,  C20: 80,  C21: 8,  C22: 1000,  C23: 8,  C24: 0,  C25: 0,  C26: 25,  C29: 2000,  C30: 275,  C31: 250,  C32: 875,  F4: "{{C5}}",  F5: "{{C7}}",  F6: "{{I21}}",  F7: "{{F24}}",  F8: "{{C29}}",  F9: "{{F4}} + {{F5}} + {{F6}} + {{F7}} + {{F8}}",  F11: "{{F9}}",  F12: "{{C6}}",  F13: "{{F11}} + {{F12}}",  F15: "{{C5}}",  F16: "{{C7}}",  F17: "{{C6}}",  F18: "{{F15}} + {{F16}} + {{F17}}",  F20: "{{F27}}",  F21: "{{C30}}",  F22: "{{C31}}",  F23: "{{C32}}",  F24: "{{F20}} + {{F21}} + {{F22}} + {{F23}}",  F26: "{{I11}}",  F27: "{{F26}} * 9 / 400",  I4: "{{F18}}",  I5: "{{F24}}",  I6: "{{C29}}",  I7: "{{C17}}",  I8: "{{I35}}",  I9: "{{I26}}",  I10: "{{C14}} * -1",  I11: "{{I4}} + {{I5}} + {{I6}} + {{I7}} + {{I8}} + {{I9}} - {{I10}}",  I13: "{{I11}}",  I14: "{{C11}}",  I15: "{{C12}}",  I16: null,  I18: "{{I35}}",  I19: "{{C15}}",  I20: "{{C17}}",  I21: "{{I18}} + {{I19}} + {{I20}}",  I23: "{{F13}}",  I24: "{{C14}} * -1",  I25: "{{C13}}",  I26: "({{I23}} + {{I24}}) * {{I25}}",  I28: "{{C20}} * {{C21}}",  I29: "{{C22}} * {{C23}}",  I30: "{{C24}} * {{C25}}",  I31: "{{C16}} * -1",  I32: "{{C11}} * {{C26}} / 365",  I33: "{{C20}} * 12",  I34: "{{C24}} * 12",  I35: "{{I28}} + {{I29}} + {{I30}} + {{I31}} + {{I32}} + {{I33}} + {{I34}}"}

var key="I35", value=relationTable[key];
console.log(value);
// or

key="{{I35}}", value=relationTable[key.replace(/[\{\}]/g,"")];
console.log(value);
```